# MPDF showing an extra page at the end

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have used mpdf for generating pdf from html.

There is one problem that this generated pdf showing one page extra. If content is end at page 1 then it generates 2 pages and if content ends at page 2 then it generates three pages.

Here is my code-

```
<?php 

include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('fsalbertpro','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0);

$html='----'; // this variables contain all css and HTML to be shown in PDF

ob_clean(); // cleaning the buffer before Output()

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

Then how Can I remove the last blank page.?

Comment: Hi, have you managed to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. At one point I had a

```
style="page-break-after:always"
```

which lead to the empty page. After removing it, the empty page disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

While tracking my code to find solution I noticed that the empty page had occurred after using certain class name! The only solution then was the class renaming!

I had:

```
<div class="A4 paper" ...>
```

By renaming "paper" class empty page disappeared!

```
<div class="A4 papir" ...>
```

With no change inside class content!

Comment: i didnt fix still how can resolve the issue. mdpf added first empty/blank page

Answer (score 0):

Please, validate the correct html markup of your content.

I was missing

```
</div>
```

which resulted in a blank page being displayed.