# ANy way to remove blank pages generated by MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

How do we get the blank page(s) generated by MPDF. I use the following codes to delete an extra blank page at the end of the document. But this code will not work if the MPDF generates two or more blank pages at the end.

```
$blankpage = $mpdf->page + 1;
$mpdf->DeletePages($blankpage);
$mpdf->Output("file.pdf", 'I');
```

The code isn't a solution if the generated pdf is one page only. So the best approach would be to get the number of blank pages. I don't know how to get the blank page even after googling and looking through the pages of the documentation in Github. Please help.

Note: The method `DeletePages()` method is also undocumented. I found it on someone's comment. Using the pagebreak produces blank page. But I need to use pagebreak in my document.

Comment: Seems like it would be better to avoid creating the blank pages to begin with. Is it normal for MPDF to do that?

Comment: I have to force pagebreak. That is the one that produces the blank page.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079142/mpdf-showing-an-extra-page-at-the-end

Comment: This is a know limitation documented here https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/known-issues.html#blank-pages-or-some-sections-missing the suggested work around is to  increase the value of `pcre.backtrack_limit` at runtime if your system allows;

Comment: That solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documented behaviour](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/known-issues.html#blank-pages-or-some-sections-missing) of mPDF. The suggested solution is to increase the value of `pcre.backtrack_limit` at runtime.

Comment: The fix you mention is for mPDF bugging out on too large chunks and returning empty pages where a real page should be.

The question is about *added* blank pages.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to get the blank page even after googling and looking through the pages of the documentation in Github.

You can easily add as many blankpages as you want by adding tag `<pagebreak>` to your source html